# Search through Global Address List

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, office-interop, outlook-2010

Is there a way to search for only givenName or LastName or emailaddress of a Contact in GAL?. Currently I have these code:

```
Private Sub QuickSearch() 'Working!
    Dim oApp As New Outlook.Application
    Dim eu As Outlook.ExchangeUser = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").AddressLists("Global Address List").AddressEntries("Justin Timberlake").GetExchangeUser()
    If Not eu Is Nothing Then
        response.write(eu.Name + ": " + eu.Alias + ", " + eu.FirstName + ", " + eu.LastName + ", " + eu.MobileTelephoneNumber + ", " + eu.Department + ", " + eu.PrimarySmtpAddress)
    End If
    oApp.Quit()
End Sub
```

Well, this one works like a Quick Search through the AddressList GAL. but one problem arises is that for example I have these contact names:

**- Justin Bieber**

**- Justin Timberlake**

And I searched for **Justin**, only **Justin Bieber** will be the result as it is the first one to be seen on the list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop at AddressEntries and then iterate through the list

```
    Dim oApp As New Outlook.Application
    Dim aeList As Outlook.AddressEntries = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").AddressLists("Global Address List").AddressEntries("Justin Timberlake")
    If Not aeList Is Nothing Then
        For Each ae As Outlook.AddressEntry aeList
            Dim eu As Outlook.ExchangeUser = ae.GetExchangeUser()
            response.write(eu.Name + ": " + eu.Alias + ", " + eu.FirstName + ", " + eu.LastName + ", " + eu.MobileTelephoneNumber + ", " + eu.Department + ", " + eu.PrimarySmtpAddress)
        Next
    End If
```